# Calculating Double Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

$$\sum_{i=0}^ni^2\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}1$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^n[x^i]\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1-x}[x^{n-i}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$
In the double sum above, I understand why $i^2= [x^i]\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1-x}$ but I don't understand why $\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}1=[x^{n-i}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

But I do know that $1 =[x^{n-i}]\frac{1}{(1-x)}$ and $[x^n]$ is the coefficient of $x^n$ in a generating series.

Any explicit idea to clear the confusion in the air?

Comment: Sir @epi163sqrt , this forms a part of your solution to a particular question. I just need clarification on this part. Hoping you see this comment. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$[x^{n-i}] \frac1{(1-x)^2} = [x^{n-i}] \frac d{dx} \frac1{1-x} = n-i+1 = \sum_{j=0}^{n-i}1$$

since

$$\frac1{1-x} = \sum_{n\ge0} x^n \stackrel{d/dx}{\implies} \frac1{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n\ge0} (n+1)x^n$$

(provided $|x|<1$) and because the sum $\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-i}$ consists of exactly $(n-i)-0+1 = n-i+1$ terms.

Comment: Wow! Explicit Enough. Thanks a lot for finding time to respond, Comrade